# Is it safe to store all of a user's data in a single file?

Tags: java

I'm creating a project for a university class, I chose to make a small inventory manager for stores and such.

I created a `User` class that saves all of the user's basic data such as his name, balance and such. There's also classes for products, clients, providers, etc.

But then I figured I could just create `ArrayLists` of all the other classes (I.e:

```
public List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>()
```

inside the `User` class so I can just serialize/deserialize that file and not have to worry about others however, the idea is that the user will be able to save as many objects as he wants, which could amount to thousands, so saving it all in a single file could lead to disaster, but since I'm completely new to this serializing thing I have no idea of how true that is.

Another thing I wonder if at some point the file could be so big that it would take some time to load, in which case I'd like to implement threads to divide the job, which I don't think can be done for loading a single file, but I'm also still learning threads so I wouldn't know. Sp in the end I'd like to know all the things that could go wrong if I end up sticking to this implementation or if it's actually better this way in this case (doubt it).

[Here's the code](https://github.com/AlfaLobo/Manager) in case anyone wants to see it although it's still a mess, it's in Spanish and most of the classes do nothing, the only ones that really do anything are Usuario, Inicio, CrearCuenta, MenuPrincipal, Registro Producto, PopupCompra, Compra Producto and Inventario, but my question should explain everything I need so that's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to use it for commercial/production use:
**No**

If it's a one-time university project that will only exist in records after the demo:
**Probably**.

One major reason against using a single file as source of truth is that maintaining ACID property would be tricky as multiple threads access it and also the system will be difficult to scale-up.

Better consider something like a database which abstracts all these details and lets you focus on business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Such projects for a relatively novel developer live be speed, maintaining overview, not losing oneself in time consuming details.

So I would give a pragmatic solution: go for what is rapidly realizable.
Do not use a binary format but text (text files or a database + SQL tool).

What you do not want to do, is writing much boiler plate code, saving and loading many fields.

1. Saving a java object like User might well be done with JAXB and annotations, say saving to XML. I used that a lot.
2. Alternatively there is the database. Object/Relational mapping, JAXP is done for instance with eclipseLink (or hibernate). Maybe an embedded database like H2, to lessen the installation scope.

Try out what gets you up and running fast, in separate test projects. You can use unit tests (Test Driven Development) to develop such approaches.

Many files in same format risks a future version change.

Answer:

- Take care not drifting in details
- Use what is works (without unclear functionality, can be checked, costs 2-3 days)